# Sublime Text 4, al crear o modificar un archivo en cualquier lenguaje al intentar guardar lo borra su contenido

Tags: sublimetext

Buenas he tenido unos problemas con sublime text 4, desde su versión 4121 presenta lo siguiente al crear un archivo nuevo PHP ó HTML, o al modificar algún archivo existente y a intentar guardarlo borra por completo todo el contenido del mismo.

Para corregir este problema he tenido que eliminar la instalación que tengo del mismo sin que me quede nada del registro del mismo en Ubuntu 20.04.

Me funciona por un tiempo bien, pero de repente comienza hacer lo mismo y no puedo trabajar.

Tienen alguna idea del por que hace esto, y como lo podría corregir y gracias de antemanos por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Esta por la version 4126, actualízalo para empezar. ¿Los archivos que te pasa eso estan en local o accedes a ellos remotamente en un servidor?  Lo digo porque si son remotos quizas tienes fallos de conexion y se corrompen los datos.  Yo siempre trabajo con ellos en remoto mediante ssh y no recuerdo que me hubiera pasado esto, aunque si es cierto que quizás si me pasó cuando lo hacia por ftp pelado.  Si se te borran los datos con Control+S siempre puedes tirar atras y recuperarlos con Control-Z.

Comment: Gracias por tu repuesta, lo tengo actualizado a 4126, y los archivos los tengo local, aunque también la problemática no se si sera por la licencia

Comment: Dudo que sea por la licencia, seria muy mala propaganda para ellos y no les interesa. Otra cosa seria que lo hubieras intentado crackear, en ese caso no se si ellos lo detectan y lo hacen de forma expresa (tambien lo dudo, pero no tanto).  En mi caso siempre guardo con Control+S, y hasta que no veo que está guardado en la barra de estado inferior no lo cierro (lo digo porque algunos paquetes como PHP Code Sniffer se toman su tiempo en analizarlo mientras se guarda, aunque eso es configurable).

Comment: Gracias masterguru, hice otras pruebas y solo me da con los archivos php, también uso es ctrl + S, para guardar mi código, lo que me estoy imaginando es que sea un conflicto generado por alguno de los plugins instalados por mi para agilizar el desarrollo de los sistemas, pero son los que siempre he utilizado desde que empece a usar sublime text como editor desde el año 2012 en cada una de sus versiones hasta la actual, y como dije en mi pregunta me comenzó a dar este problema desde la version 4121

Comment: Si, tiene toda la pinta de ser eso.  Tendras que depurar eso e irlos desactivando y activando hasta que des con el conflictivo. Para ello pulsa Control+Shift+P y escribe `disable` y selecciona `Package Control: Disable Package` y te aparecerá una lista donde puedes seleccionar el paquete a desactivar.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Suerte! Cuando encuentres el paquete te sugiero que te crees una respuesta a ti mismo con la solución para que la comunidad lo vea. Al cabo de 12 horas, creo,  podras aceptartela tu mismo y asi no quedará pendiente de responder eternamente, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru, Ya logre conseguir el paquete que me estaba dando problema, revisando la consola, ya que allí sublime text muestra todo lo ejecutado, vi un error en el siguiente plugin PHPTools, lo desactive y ya no barra el código al guardar

Comment: Perfecto! :-)  ¿Quieres que redacte yo una respuesta?  Lo digo para indicar los pasos de la depuración tambien, por si algun dia tambien le ocurre a otro con otro paquete.

Comment: Te lo agradeceria mucho ya que con tu guia logre la solución, que lo comentes

Comment: @masterguru por favor redacta una repuesta y gracias

Comment: Hecho!  Si acaso borra tu respuesta y acepta la mia, y listos :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En caso de problemas de este tipo con el editor de textos **Sublime** sugiero realizar los siguientes pasos para su depuración (el orden es a voluntad):

- Siempre tener el **Sublime** *actualizado a la última versión*, por si, en primera instancia, se hubiera corregido el problema entre versiones.
- **Desactivar** los paquetes sospechosos mediante `Control-Shift-P`, luego escribir `disable`, luego seleccionar `Package Control: Disable Package` y al aparecer una lista de los paquetes seleccionar el sospechoso.  E ir descartándolos a medida que se realizan las pruebas.
- Revisar la **consola** de *Sublime* para ver todo lo que éste realiza y encontrar posibles errores relacionados, pues con ello se puede identificar si también es un paquete y desactivarlo tal como está explicado en el punto anterior. Para ver la consola pulsar sobre `View | Show console` en el menú superior.

Según ha declarado el propio OP (Original Poster) en su caso el problema venia dado por el paquete *PHPTools*, que ha desactivado solucionando su problema específico.

Answer (score 0):

finalmente luego de buscar como resolver el problema parece que ya lo tengo, mi primera pista fue que solo pasaba con archivos php por lo que supuse que se trataba de los de ese lenguaje, descubrí que muchos de ellos traen una configuración default y una para usuario y que varias no funcionan correctamente si no están las configuraciones en los archivos de usuario ya que los trae vacíos hay que copiar el contenido de los que dicen defaul y modificarlos de acuerdo a los parámetros de tu entorno investigue cuales son los mas importantes aquí hay un manual de muy bien explicado.
https://styde.net/instalar-php-code-sniffer-en-sublime-text/
re inicié el sublime y me salio otro error en la consola, diferente pero similar para un paquete que se llama PHPConnector, investigue de que se trata para que sirve o cual es su utilidad, sin embargo hay muy poca información lo cual me llevo a no saber que poner en un campo que dice SRT o algo por el estilo que nunca logré saber para que es así que simplemente lo elimine desde preferencias, control de paquetes quitar paquete re inicio de sublime  y voala ya no me borra las letras ni aparece error en la consola éxito colegas.